# DataTable is distorted in firefox browser

Tags: javascript, css, datatable

I am using datatable for data population in my application but in my application datatable is coming properly in IE 9 but its is complete distorted in Firefox browser.Can anyone help me .This is my table i am using

```
 <table width='100%' align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="10"
    border="1" name="userSTPForm" id="metalPager">
    <thead>
        <tr >               
            <th style="width: 130px;">SAPCODE</th>
            <th style="width: 165px;">FIRST NAME</th>
            <th style="width: 165px;">LAST NAME</th>
            <th style="width: 130px;">Organization Name </th>
            <th style="width: 130px;">MAIL</th>
            <th style="width: 130px;">Mobile</th>
            <th style="width: 130px;">STATUS</th>               
            <c:if test="${makePaymentFlag==true}">
                <th style="width: 130px;">
                    PAYMENT
                </th>
            </c:if>
            <c:if test="${isTmlAdminRole==true}">
                <th style="width: 170px;">
                    APPROVE/REJECT
                </th>
            </c:if>   

</tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
```

Comment: Not sure how anyone can help you with no references or indication of what is happening

Comment: @ScottMitchell can you see now ??

Answer (score 0):

Modern browsers some times reject deprecated attributes. Because of there adaptability to new versions of html, css and etc. It's better to use latest attributes to style and to make your markup. And also it's good practice to test your application on a chrome, firefox or any modern browser. Internet Explorer some times block scripts or it can't work properly with out needed extensions.

Comment: but my problem is that in IE it is working fine,but distorted in firefox.i have left the code here see if u can help

Comment: I didn't see any different between IE and Firefox output of your page. I used IE11 and firefox 17.0 versions. But there are few different because their default font sizes and some of measurement not based on same standard. As u haven't defined styles like font sizes It can be cause to distort your page. Try some newer versions of browser and clean up your cashes.